# Hibernate Many-To-Many adds duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA Hibernate and I'm having a small problem: My Many-To-Many relationship adds duplicates to the database when an author already exists. When the author doesn't exist all is inserted well. The code is the following:

```
if (existentAuthor != null) {
  b.getAuthors().add(existentAuthor);
  ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
  existentAuthor.getBooks().add(b);
  bookrepo.saveBook(b);
  authorepo.saveAuthor(existentAuthor);
}
```

Author and Book classes:

```
public class Author {

    @Column(name="author_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

    private String name;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "author_books",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}
    )
    private List<Book> books ;
```

```
public class Book {

    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books",fetch =FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Author> authors ;
```

Please help me with a hint, as I tried everything on the internet.

Comment: How does your code in `bookrepo` and `authorrepo` looks like? Are you using there `persist` or `merge`? Where `existentAuthor` is comming from? Is your code that takes care of adding `existentAuthor` to `Book` in transaction context or not? Provide more code, as it is it's hard to investigate what might be wrong.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: this is doing nothing: `ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();`. Also I see Jackson annotations in the entities, hinting that they are used as DTOs. If the `existentAuhor` comes from the client and you simply persist it as new, it could create duplicates (again, see Martin's comment)